# How do I close a Flask-SQLAlchemy connection that I used in a Thread?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

When I query a Flask-SQLAlchemy model in a Thread, it seems like the database connection is never closed. Here is a test case:

```
from threading import Thread
from sqlalchemy.pool import NullPool
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import Flask
db = SQLAlchemy()
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql:///testdb'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS'] = {
    'poolclass': NullPool,
}
db.app = app
db.init_app(app)


class TestModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "test_table"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)


@app.route('/test-connection')
def test_connection():
    def run_test():
        models = TestModel.query.all()
        print(models)
    thread = Thread(target=run_test)
    thread.start()
    return "OK"


app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

When I run my route, it permanently leaves an `idle in transaction` query in my pg_stat_activity table:

```
testdb=# select query, state from pg_stat_activity where query like '%test_table%' and query not like '%pg_stat_activity%';
                 query                  |        state        
----------------------------------------+---------------------
 SELECT test_table.id AS test_table_id +| idle in transaction
 FROM test_table                        | 
(1 row)
```

That row doesn't show up if I call the `run_test` function synchronously instead of in the Thread. In production, this is causing my application to run out of database connections and crash. How can I close my Flask-SQLAlchemy database connection after using it in a thread?

I'm using Python 3.8.6, SQLAlchemy 1.3.18, and Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.4.4.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We had faced a similar issue with open connections. Though the DB in question was SQL Server, I believe the same solution should work here.

We added a method to close the DB connection.

```
def cleanup(session):
    """
    This method cleans up the session object and closes the connection pool using the dispose 
    method.
    """
    session.close()
    engine_container.dispose()
```

The engine_container is defined as:
`engine_container = db.get_engine(app)`

We called this method from the finally block after every request.

```
finally:
    cleanup(db.session)
```

With this change, your code should look like:

```
from threading import Thread
from sqlalchemy.pool import NullPool
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import Flask

db = SQLAlchemy()
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql:///testdb'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS'] = {
    'poolclass': NullPool,
}
db.app = app
db.init_app(app)
engine_container = db.get_engine(app)


class TestModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "test_table"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)


@app.route('/test-connection')
def test_connection():
    def run_test():
        try:
            models = TestModel.query.all()
            print(models)
        except Exception as err:
            raise err
        finally:
            cleanup(db.session)

    thread = Thread(target=run_test)
    thread.start()
    return "OK"


def cleanup(session):
    """
    This method cleans up the session object and also closes the connection pool using the dispose method.
    """
    session.close()
    engine_container.dispose()


app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue you're experiencing has to do with the connection pooling that is going on behind the scenes. Good resources to read might be this [SQLAlchemy resource](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/pooling.html#pool-setting-recycle) on setting the pool recycle parameter, and this [SQLAlchemy resource](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/pooling.html#pool-reset-on-return) on the reset on return behavior.

```py
SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS = {
    pool_size=20,
    pool_reset_on_return='commit', # looks like postgres likes this more than rollback
    pool_timeout=5, # try a low value here maybe
}
```

It also looks like there is some useful information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613812/how-do-i-make-flask-sqlalchemy-reuse-db-connections?rq=1). It might be useful to create a custom function that essentially closes the session connection following a successful response.

Unfortunately, I don't have much experience with postgres myself, and had to tinker my way to the promised-land with MySQL connection pooling. I'm imagine the answer will actually be found somewhere in the Postgres Documentation, like it was in the MySQL Documentation for myself.

Answer (score 0):

Use with statement, there is a test:

```
def test():
    with db.session() as dbss:
        qss = TestModel.query.session
        assert dbss == qss
    with db.session():
        TestModel.query.filter(...)...
```