# How to close connection properly with SQLAlchemy to avoid the error "sqlalchemy.exc.TimeoutError: QueuePool limit of size 5 overflow 10 reached"

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have the Postgres database. I'm using Flask and SQLAclhemy.
Recently, I had a lot of errors **"sqlalchemy.exc.TimeoutError: QueuePool limit of size 5 overflow 10 reached"**. When I see my server is irresponsive I have to reboot it.
I need to figure out what I'm doing wrong and how to avoid this issue.
I use only 2 approaches in the code:

1. Working with models, for example:

```
users = User.query.order_by(desc(User.created))\
                    .limit(users_per_page)\
                    .offset((page_number - 1) * users_per_page)\
                    .all()
```

2. Doing direct queries on sessions like:

```
with contextlib.closing(db.session) as session:

   data = session.query(task_function, Stat.activity, func.count()).filter(
                        Stat.created.in_(subq)).group_by(period_function, 
                        Stat.activity_detail).order_by(desc(period_function))
```

I started seeing the problems when I created and deployed the second piece of code.
Doesn't it work work?
What else can be done?

Here is how I set up the connection: I have the db URL in my environments, then just create the instance of SQLAlchemy:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()
```

I saw a lot of suggestions but I can't figure out how to apply them because they all use some "manual" connection like calling `create_engine` function which I don't use.

Note. My database is hosted on AWS RDS.

UPD. I was able to fix the issue, at least I don't see hanging sessions anymore and the number of connections is fine. I added `session.commit()` into the "with" block. Also, I closed the session whenever it's possible:

```
global engine_container
    with app.app_context():
        if engine_container is None:
            engine_container = db.get_engine()

def cleanup_session(session):
    """
    This method cleans up the session object and also closes the connection pool using the dispose method.
    """
    global engine_container
    session.close()
    engine_container.dispose()
    return
```

from this post [How do I close a Flask-SQLAlchemy connection that I used in a Thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66876181/how-do-i-close-a-flask-sqlalchemy-connection-that-i-used-in-a-thread)

Comment: Read [SQLAlchemy connection pooling](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/pooling.html).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver can you suggest the concrete actions I can take? The approach in this article based on the direct connection which I don't use what I mentioned in the post.

Comment: Read [Basic Usage](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html). Use the `engine` context manager to handle the reuse of connections.

Comment: Realized  I pointed you at the wrong link. From here [SQLAlchemy connection pooling](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/pooling.html): *SQLAlchemy includes several connection pool implementations which integrate with the Engine. They can also be used directly for applications that want to add pooling to an otherwise plain DBAPI approach.*  Where the DBAPI approach is found in the *Constructing a Pool* section. If that doesn't work then I believe you will need to use an external pooler.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12044776/5320906) answer your question?